# Listing 7.15 - LogService - Java Concurrency in Practice - Attempting to add a wait termination with timeout

Tags: java, concurrency, timeout

In listing 7.15 of "Java Concurrency in Practice" there is an example of producer/consumer with no wait for termination on the method stop.

The main thread in the original code does not wait for the log thread to finish. This can cause issue especially when logging to a file and the file needs to be manipulated after the stop. An exception can be generated if the consumer is still using the file.

Does the following code work adding wait for termination with timeout on the stop method?

```
public class LogService {

private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
private final PrintWriter writer;
private final Object lock;
private boolean shutdown;
private boolean prepareShutdown;
private int reservations;

public LogService(Writer writer) {
    this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    this.loggerThread = new LoggerThread();
    this.writer = new PrintWriter(writer);
    this.lock = new Object();
}

public void start() {
    loggerThread.start();
}

public void stop(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        prepareShutdown = true;
    }
    loggerThread.interrupt();
    try {
        loggerThread.join(timeout);
    } finally {
        synchronized (lock) {
            shutdown = true;
        }
        loggerThread.interrupt();
    }
}

public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (shutdown || prepareShutdown)
            throw new IllegalStateException(/* ... */);
        ++reservations;
    }
    queue.put(msg);
}

private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (shutdown || prepareShutdown
                                && reservations == 0)
                            break;
                    }
                    String msg = queue.take();
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        --reservations;
                    }
                    writer.println(msg);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */
                }
            }
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Does the following code work adding wait for termination with timeout on the stop method?" Can you rephrase that? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: The original code in the book does not allow for the calling thread to wait for the loggerThread. I added that behavior with the loggerThread.join(timeout). Now the calling thread blocks until all tasks have completed execution, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first. My question is: is the code I posted well written? Can it be improved?